# PHP - I want the user to have no possibility to upvote more than one time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, data-modeling, social-networking

I am working on a small social network with PHP and MySQL
I want the users to have the possibility to upvote a post, and I already did this but the problem is that I want the user to be able to upvote only one time.

Here is my PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['heart']))
{ 
  $identificateur = $_POST['hide'];
  $Q = "UPDATE posts  SET avis = avis + 1 where id=$identificateur ";
  $bdd->query($Q);
}
```

This is the form of the upvote button :

```
<form action="p.php" method="POST">
        <label><?php 
        if ($avis != 0)
                    {
                        echo $avis; 
                    }
        ?></label>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$id" ?>" name="hide">
        <input type="submit" value=" " id="heart" name="heart"> 
</form>
```

Every user should have the right to click on the up vote icon only once.
Thank you very much in  advance.

Comment: You must have a table that will have an entry for a user and his upvote on a post.

Comment: My suggestion is, you need to create a new db table to store which person had upvote which post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a second table, that has two fields, `post_id` and `voter_id`. (`post_voter`).`post_id` has a foreign key containing the id of the post table and `voter_id` has foreign key to the user table. This table specifies voters of a post and posts that users have voted for. When a user tries to upvote a post, you must check `post_voter` table and get count of rows which have the `post_id` equal to the post's id and `voter_id` equal to the user's id. If count = 0, this means the user has not upvoted the post, yet, and he can vote for it now. Otherwise, the user upvoted the post already and he can't upvote it again.